# what are the components to ensure secure execution of code

Tags: c#, .net

In interview, interviewer asked me one question that,
What are the components to ensure secure execution of code in .net. I tried in google but failed. Can any one give me the answer or link?

I found one word document. In that I found that components of secure code execution are Assembly loader, code verifier, JIT. Is this correct?

Comment: This could refer to **many** things. Though the .Net `Garbage Collector` (automatic allocation and disposal of memory) springs to mind immediately

Comment: This question is off topic.. ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the CLR security model. Microsoft has a good article about it.

Summary:

> The common language runtime of the .NET Framework has its own secure
>   execution model that isn't bound by the limitations of the operating
>   system it's running on. In addition, unlike the old principal-based
>   security, the CLR enforces security policy based on where code is
>   coming from rather than who the user is. This model, called code
>   access security, makes sense in today's environment because so much
>   code is installed over the Internet and even a trusted user doesn't
>   know when that code is safe.

[The Security Infrastructure of the CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188939.aspx#S1)

Answer (score 0):

My answer off the top of my head would be a [Try-Catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) block. You will want to catch exceptions by type to give meaningful output to your user (if need be), but a general exception can work great for internal testing.

```c#
try
{
    /*Some code which could throw exceptions.*/
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}\nStack Trace: {1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace);
}
```

However, I am only going off of the idea that "secure execution" means without crashing.

Answer (score 0):

"Secure execution of code" could mean many things. But I think the interviewer asked for **Code Access Security**, which is the security model of .net environment.

The CAS is not the same for all framework versions  and is a complex subject to explain here. Basically its allow or disallow code execution based on the assembly and code notation, assembly origin, trust level, etc.

You can get some intro here:

2.0 or 3.5 => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5tk9z76(v=vs.90)

4.0 or 4.5 => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5tk9z76(v=vs.100)